# using Jquery variable from mysql

Tags: php, jquery

I was searching for the answer but I couldn't found one for the specific problem, someone says something about ajax or json but I have no idea how to use this things, so I decided to ask a question.

Actualy I'm saving the values from a skill calculator in mysql using php/mysql and jquery for the calculating.

What I need at moment is take a number from mysql and use it as variable, maybe somthing like this:

```
ranksalvo[0] == 
    <?php
        mysql_select_db("skill");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skillrank WHERE ID = '71' ");
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $rank1 = $rows['rank1'];
    ?>;

if(ranksalvo[0] == 1){      
    $('.archerrank2').slideDown(1000);
}
```

As you can see its just a very bad example, but I think it shows exactly what I want also why I couldn't find a good enough answer when I was searching it.

Thank you!

```
<form action="conexao/conexao.php" method="post">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var ranksalvo = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
        var skillsalvo = [0,0,0,0,0,0];

        var ranksalvo[0] =  
        <?php
            mysql_select_db("skill");
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skillrank WHERE ID = '71' ");
            $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $rank1 = $rows['rank1'];
            echo "$rank1";
        ?>;

        if(ranksalvo[0] == 1){

            $('#rank1s').slideDown(1000);
            $('#rank2s').slideDown(1000);
            $('#rank3s').slideDown(1000);
            $('#rank4s').slideDown(1000);
            $('#multishot').slideDown(1000);
            $('#fulldraw').slideDown(1000);
            $('#swiftstep').slideDown(1000);
            $('#kneelingshot').slideDown(1000);         
            $('.archerrank2').slideDown(1000);
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: to assign values you use only one equal sign ranksalvo[0] = ........  '==' is to compare...

Comment: Ops, sorry that double ==, but it was just an example, I haven't tried this code. Its just an example and I can't belive its right. ^^

Comment: "... exactly what I want ..."!! What is the scenario - initial page build or fetching content for a page that's already served?

Comment: Well, the page is already built, I'm changing it to receive value from mysql.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you correctly identified the need for AJAX, which means intercommunication of a displayed web page with a sever (typically the same server that served the page).

Comment: I understand, is it possible to take a number from mysql and use it as variable in a jquery code with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

would be something like:

```
var ranksalvo[0] = 
    <?php
        mysql_select_db("skill");
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM skillrank WHERE ID = '71' ");
        $rows = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        $rank1 = $rows['rank1'];
    ?>;

if(ranksalvo[0] == 1){      
    $('.archerrank2').slideDown(1000);
}
```

Comment: Gonna try straight away!

Comment: it should work.... just make sure you catch the error if your database returns a null or a NaN

Comment: you would need to run it on your server since you are retrieveing data from a database to initialize the variable. yo can use <?php echo "value" ?>if you don't want to query a database... just to test...

Comment: Unfortunately the php code is crashing the whole code, if I erase only the php party the code backs to work normally.

Comment: try with <?php echo 1 ?> instead of the database call

Comment: It won't work, cuz the value needs to be the value from mysql.

Comment: can you debug and make sure you are actually getting the expected value from the database? in this case you should be getting the value 1 (as a number... not as a string)

Comment: i'm getting this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: please share the code to take a look

Comment: I'm doing it local, gonna need to create a new db somewhere and post to show it.
I can like compact everything and upload it somewhere...

Comment: just paste the piece of code that retrieve the value from the database...

Comment: Done, check up there where I have edited the code.

Comment: you are not getting anything from the database you are passing   echo "$rank1" as a string it should be   echo $rank1; without the quotes

Comment: The if statement of your javascript will never be true because ranksalvo[0] value would be "$rank1"

Comment: Gonna try without quotes

Comment: Still the same problem, the php code crash all the code, since my code is really giant its funny to see what happens when it crash. ^^

Comment: you need to make sure you are getting a value from your db man... it looks like you are not getting any value.... and if thats the case, the condition will never be true

Comment: I found the problem, for some reason this code doesn't work, if I just put echo $rank1; its enough to get syntax error again, then I made it different.
I created an input where the value is the php code and after I made the Jquery get the value from this input, and finally it worked.